# Bigquery - Column name name is ambiguous at [2:3]

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to this -  The below query is showing an error - employees and departments are tables and departmnet_id is the column name.

SELECT
name,
department_id,
role
FROM
employee_data.employees
INNER JOIN
employee_data.departments
ON
'august-emitter-173906.employee_data.employees.department_id' = 'august-emitter-173906.employee_data.departments.department_id'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your department_id in your select could refer to either department id from departments or employees.

Try using an alias like:

```
SELECT 
emp.name, emp.department_id, emp.role 
FROM employee_data.employees emp
INNER JOIN employee_data.departments  dep
ON emp.department_id = dep.department_id
```

- Note: not sure which one is the correct table to use in your case but simply swap the alias as needed.

Example error:
As you can see here, I am not using an alias, similar to your question, and there is an ambiguity error:
[image]

Example solution:
With alias the ambiguity error is resolved
[image]

Comment: Thanks, So I tried and up to this point query is working fine
SELECT
  name,
  department_id,
  role
FROM
  employee_data.employees
JOIN
  employee_data.departments
ON

ANd error happens when I add this statement 

 'august-emitter-173906.employee_data.employees.department_id' = 'august-emitter-173906.employee_data.departments.department_id'

Comment: As I said the issue is following

" 'august-emitter-173906.employee_data.employees.department_id' = 'august-emitter-173906.employee_data.departments.department_id'

Comment: That is because when you introduce the second table it creates ambiguity, meaning department_id in your select statement can now come from either table.  The use of the alias' as I have in my example allows you to simply reference the appropriate one.

Comment: I have added screenshots to elaborate